# TryCatch with Websocket on two IPs is not handled in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a websocket listening on some interfaces so the client could call more than one ip. I don't have a dns for these IPs. This failes even in the try block

```
        window.onload = function() {
        ws = "";
        try {
          ws_connection = "ws://" + lblInfoIP.value + ":9080/websockets";
          ws = new WebSocket(ws_connection);
        }
        catch(err) {
          ws_connection = "ws://127.0.01:9080/websockets";
          ws = new WebSocket(ws_connection);
        }
        ws.onmessage = function(msg) { showInfo(msg.data); };
        ws.onerror = function(evt){ alert ('Websocket failed with ' + evt.data) };
    }
```

manually using the same ip as the called url works.

How would I correctly handle that ?

Is there somesthing like ws_connection = "ws://" + called_url + "/websockets"; ?

Comment: What do you mean with "called_url" ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your try/catch construct, use a simple "or" (`||`) operation:

```js
window.onload = function () {

   let ws =  new WebSocket(`ws://${lblInfoIP.value || "127.0.01:9080"}/websockets`)

    ws.onmessage = function (msg) { showInfo(msg.data); };
    ws.onerror = function (evt) { alert('Websocket failed with ' + evt.data) };

}
```

In development, set `lblInfoIP.value` to `null` or "`undefined`".
Or use "`document.location.host`:9080"

Comment: thanks            let connection = "ws://" + document.location.host + "/websockets";
            let ws =  new WebSocket(connection); did work